# localhost refused to connect when using node js , mysql and docker

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to include mysql and nodejs in my docker-compose file. I don't get any errors but when I enter localhost:3006 in my webbrowser I get the localhost refused to connect error message.
I addes app.listen at the bottom of the code , so that it listens to port 3006 but I still get no output when going on localhost:3006.

Could someone give me a hint?

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8005 
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

docker-compse:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  nodejs:
    build: 
      context: .
    image: amakundu/nodejs-mysql-app
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=moe-mysql-app
      - MYSQL_USER=moeuser
      - MYSQL_PASS=moepass
      - MYSQL_DB=moe_db
    volumes:
      - ./www/:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "30001:8005"
    container_name: moe-nodejs-app
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.21
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=tsubasa 
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=locatons14
    container_name: moe-mysql-app
```

server.js file:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
const port = 3006;
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); // Body parser for fetch posted data
var responseStr = "MySQL Data:";
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/',function(req,res){
   
   var mysqlHost = process.env.MYSQL_HOST || 'localhost';
   var mysqlPort = process.env.MYSQL_PORT || '3306';
   var mysqlUser = process.env.MYSQL_USER || 'root';
   var mysqlPass = process.env.MYSQL_PASS || '';
   var mysqlDB   = process.env.MYSQL_DB   || 'mydatabase';

   var connectionOptions = {
     host: mysqlHost,
     port: mysqlPort,
     user: mysqlUser,
     password: mysqlPass,
     database: mysqlDB
   };

   console.log('MySQL Connection config:');
   console.log(connectionOptions);

   var connection = mysql.createConnection(connectionOptions);
   
   connection.connect();
 
   connection.query(queryStr, function (error, results, fields) {
     if (error) throw error;
     
     responseStr = '';

     results.forEach(function(data){
        responseStr += data.ITEM_NAME + ' : ';
        console.log(data);
     });

     if(responseStr.length == 0)
        responseStr = 'No records found';

     console.log(responseStr);

     res.status(200).send(responseStr);
   });
    
   connection.end();
});


const router = app => {
    // Display welcome message on the root
    app.get('/', (request, response) => {
        response.send({
            message: 'Welcome to the Node.js Express REST API!'
        });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example at ${port}`)
});

}
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I don't see configured network in `docker-compose`

Comment: @Anatoly do you mean the configured network for nodejs?

Comment: I mean common configured network for both containers so they can "see" each other

Comment: Not sure how I should do this. should I just add the portnumber to mysql image ?

Comment: You can try. The default network should work anyway.

Comment: so which common configured network should i add ?

Comment: No, you don't need to. Try to indicate `ports` option for DB container as well as you indicated for Node.js app

Comment: use`'MYSQL_HOST`=`mysql` (the container name) for your application. Shouldn't the `MYSQL_USER`/ `MYSQL_D{ATABASE,B}` be the same on both containers.

Comment: @Anatoly sorry I don't really know what you mean.I added ports to DB container and now it can't start the mysql app

Comment: Your Dockerfile and `docker-compose.yml` both name port 8005, but your code listens on port 3006; those need to match.  You then publish this out on port 30001, and that's the port you need to put into your browser.  (This is unrelated to the inter-container networking the above comments discuss; I'm not clear you're hitting a point where the application calls the database.)

Comment: @DavidMaze your'e right now i am getting an error message `error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist`